# Why does python split strings when adding them to sets?

Tags: python

This is my method:

```
def edge(self, f, a, b, s):
        if not (
         isinstance(f, str) and isinstance(a, str)
         and isinstance(b, str) and isinstance(s, str)):
            raise TypeError('ERROR: Edge requires string arguments.')

        elif f in self.A:
             raise ValueError('ERROR: Edge name already taken.')

        elif not trie_methods.is_gen(s):
            raise ValueError('ERROR: Edge requires a dna char for symbol.')

        else:
            self.A.add(f)
            self.dom[f] = a
            self.cod[f] = b
            self.sym[f] = s
```

This is the test and the output:

```
class test_method_edge(unittest.TestCase):
...
    def auto_name(self):
        trie = graph.Graph()
        trie.node('A')
        trie.node('B')
        f = trie_methods.name()
        trie.edge(f, 'A', 'B', 't')
        self.assertIn(f, trie.A)
        self.assertTrue(trie.dom[f] =='A')
        self.assertTrue(trie.cod[f] == 'B')
        self.assertTrue(trie.sym[f] == 't')

FAIL: test_auto (__main__.test_method_node)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_graph.py", line 40, in test_auto
    self.assertIn(n, trie.O)
AssertionError: '82Q3C1' not found in {'3', '2', '8', 'Q', '1', 'C'}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I've tried it with 'update' and 'add'. I believe strings are hashable, and sets can only take hashable objects. Is there a another restriction on the elements of a set?

Comment: There is not enough information here - you've put a lot of information in, but almost none of it is useful.  We might be able to guess that `A` is a `set`, or what `trie_methods.name()` evaluates to, or what the 40th line of the file you show is, but it's not a great way to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Strings are iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), and `set` [accepts an iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) as an argument.

As far as `set` is concerned, you're passing it a collection of some kind that you want represented as a `set` instead.

A way around this is to wrap what you're passing in as a tuple or list instead.  It will use the wrapping tuple or list as the iterable instead, and place that into the set as opposed to each individual letter.

```
>>> set("words")
set(['s', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'd'])
>>> set(("words",))
set(['words'])
```

Comment: However, a list is not hashable - won't a set not accept it?

Comment: You can't nest the array (that is, you can't have `set([["alpha"]])`), but you can use a list just fine.  `set(["alpha"])` will work.